# Can I find out width of screen programmatically in android app?

Tags: android, android-layout

Can I find out the width of screen programmatically in android app? I need to paint canvas but its width should be almost like screen and I could not  set match_parent in java part program.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get default `Display` instance and then read width/height from it:

```
int width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
int height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
```

Comment: This method is deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
```

`dm.widthPixels` contains the width and `dm.heightPixels` contains the height.

Answer (score 2):

You could also overwrite onSizeChanged(int,int,int,int) in any view and set it in there.