# Fetching Android Device Screen Size

Tags: android, screen-size

I'm searching for how to get Android device diagonal screen size in inches? I've tried a lot with e.g. below links.

[getting the screen density programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android)

[how to get android screen size programmatically, once and for all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481341/how-to-get-android-screen-size-programmatically-once-and-for-all)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get screen dimensions in pixels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/get-screen-dimensions-in-pixels)

Comment: why do you want to get size in inches?

Comment: Once you get the height and width of the device, apply **Pythagoras theorem** to get the diagonal measurement.

Comment: ThankYou.. I need in inches ..

Comment: @UditMukherjee why not post that as an answer?

Comment: To provide app to particular users having device from 4 to 7 inches only

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the device height and width from DisplayMetrics. Then apply Pythagoras theorem to get the diagonal measurement.

```
DisplayMetrics met = new DisplayMetrics();                
this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(met);// get display metrics object
String strSize = new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(Math.sqrt(((met.widthPixels / met.xdpi) * (met.widthPixels / met.xdpi)) + ((met.heightPixels / met.ydpi) * (met.heightPixels / met.ydpi))));
```

read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481341/how-to-get-android-screen-size-programmatically-once-and-for-all)

Comment: This code might solve the problem, but you should provide some details to explain what it does.

Comment: @Marcus, Thanks for that. I added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you want to restrict user to use for particular screen size.

Please follow the documentation provided from the following [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html) to distribute application based on screen size. You may need to add combinations of screen size and screen densities to filter out devices with screen size less than 4" which falls under category NORMAL.

**Please note:** 
It would be advised to put entries in manifest so that Google Play itself filter out non compatible screen sizes. 
If you programmatically check the screen size and then display a message to the user that the device is not compatible, it will be bad user experience and if its a paid app then you may need to warn user about screen size before purchasing and downloading your app.

You may need to ask your business to reconsider on the requirements on screen size! 
Screens are not normally differentiated based on exact screen sizes in inches.

Comment: But here problem is 4 inches belong to NORMAL screen ,so we can't avoid normal screen in manifest

Comment: Use density along with screen size and see if you can filter out

Comment: Yes, but result would be the same...bcz density can't filter out

Comment: you can... check the link I shared in above answer.
you can filter densities as well like:       
<compatible-screens>
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

Comment: When coming to 3 inches screen,it will accept NORMAL screen & as well it belongs to any of available four densities....so it doesn't works.But anyway thanks for your support... @ Abhinav Tyagi

Comment: then you need to ask business to reconsider their requirements?
may I know what will be the issue if it was a 3" screen?

Comment: Not an issue with 3 inches screen,but had a requirement,

Comment: You should then follow the above way. Sometimes you get such requirements and then developers need to educate their business :)

Comment: For reference https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=suzunone

Comment: But why can't we get screen diagonal size in inches .It is a BUG looks like.

Comment: This is because there are different resolutions and densities available for same screen size. Also sometimes you have bigger screen but its dpi or resolution is lesser than a smaller screen size device. This is not a bug. Its a way to categorize things related to screen size and densities.

Comment: Just follow what is said here
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html
Make your app UI to support all screen sizes below 7"

Comment: There is no issue app will run below 7 inches very fine,but requirement is an requirement right?

Comment: Is this your first app?
Requirements may change or modified even during development these days.