# Word Wrapping issue in Android

Tags: android, text, word-wrap

```
float ratio = 2.666666666666667f; // 1440/540

TextView textView = new TextView(this);

textView.setText("Ayet-i kerimelerin nazil olmasından sonra Fahr-i Kâinat Efendimiz s.a.v.’in daha fazla ibadet ile meşgul olması, nail olunan büyük ihsan ve ikramlara şükretmesiyle alakalıdır. Nitekim Hz. Aişe r. anha validemizin sorusu üzerine bunu doğrudan ifade de buyuruyorlar. Bizim açımızdan da şükrün edası gayret gerektirir. İbadet ve taatlerimizde, işlerimizde…\n\nFetih sure-i şerifi ile Fahr-i Kâinat Efendimiz s.a.v.’in ümmetinden olarak bizler de nice fetihlerle, gayret ve çabamıza karşılık ilahî mağfiret ve yardımlarla müjdeleniyoruz.\n\nMüminler olarak Cenab-ı Mevlâ’dan asla ümit kesmeden, azami gayret ve çaba göstererek mücadelemize devam ettiğimizde, müjdelendiğimiz fetihler de müyesser olacaktır inşallah.");
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,14*ratio);
textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)(510*ratio), RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.leftMargin = (int)(15*ratio);
textView.setLayoutParams(params);

root.addView(textView);
```

As seen in the image below sometimes some texts may be wrapped down to the next line where it shouldn't. The word circled in the image appears to have moved down to the next line whereas it could easily fit in the remaining space in the current line. This situation might be the result of the calculation of android text engine. The project i am working on is sensitive in that regard. What can i do to prevent this from happening?

[image]

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: you can change your textSize to be dynamic to fit (since Android OS determines the space allocation for text according to the device density).

Comment: @Andy Developer  i added the code

Comment: may be the problem is with your size. Try with COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP instead of COMPLEX_UNIT_PX. Why you set the fix ratio?

Comment: You can not set the width like 510*ratio you have to find out dynamically according to each device.

Comment: You can [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481341/how-to-get-android-screen-size-programmatically-once-and-for-all) for getting the width and height of the screen.

Comment: @Andy Developer i must work with COMPLEX_UNIT_PX for my project requirements. Also this is only a test on my device.

Comment: i don't think the problem is screen actual width or height. As seen in the image some texts could easily fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved the issue:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
   textView.setBreakStrategy(Layout.BREAK_STRATEGY_SIMPLE);
```